# ios Whatsapp Sharing not working for iphone 5s

Tags: ios, whatsapp, openurl

Here is the code. I took it from
http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013
It goes into if condition. But do nothing. This code worked for iphone 5. And in case of iphone 5s nothing happened. It is not opening Whatsapp URL.

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

Comment: Silly question: do you have Whatsapp installed in the iPhone 5S?

Comment: This was working fine for me until recent - has stopped after the recent whatsapp ios 2.12.5 update of Aug 05, 2015 :-(

Answer (score 1):

In Plist add

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not your case but I think my answer will help someone else.

I had the same issue on iOS 11 and the problem was that some customUrls are not supported anymore from `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL()`.

You have to use `UIApplication.shared.openUrl()`.

I hope this can be helpful